# Loading an image from a resource embedded in a dll

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, firebreath

I'm developing a browser plugin (npapi) using FireBreath, and in it I'm trying to embed images which I need to load at runtime.

I've been search, reading and experimenting for two days now but I can't seem to make it work.
This is the code I ended up with:

```
HMODULE hModule;
LPCWSTR path = L"nptest.dll";
GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT, path, &hModule);
LPTSTR resourceName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(106);
HBITMAP bitmap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(hModule, resourceName, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
```

The loaded bitmap seems to be empty after the execution of this code, and I can't figure out why.
At first I tried to load a PNG image, and later realized that PNGs are not supported, so I just created a BMP file using the resource editor in VS2010.
I know for sure that the BMP (with id 106) is in the compiled DLL because I used PE Explorer to check inside the DLL.

Any ideas as for why it fails to load the image resource?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the `GetModuleHandleEx()` call successful?

Comment: Yes, seems so. The result of this function call is 1 and `hModule` is not empty.

Comment: When `LoadImage()` returns `NULL`, use `GetLastError()` to find out why.

Comment: `LoadImage` does not return `NULL`, I see in the debugger that the `bitmap` variable has an address, but the bitmap image itself seems empty, i.e. `GetBitmapDimensionEx` returns 0. Also, `GetLastError` returns 0 as well.