# Embedding an image as a resource in a FireBreath plugin

Tags: cmake, embedded-resource, firebreath

While using VS (2010), I used to be able to add an image as a resource simply by going to the `Resource` view and then: `Right click project > Add > Resource > Import`.
I even asked a question about how to then load it: [Loading an image from a resource embedded in a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358248/loading-an-image-from-a-resource-embedded-in-a-dll), but that changed for some reason.

Now when I try the same thing and save the `.rc` file, I get this message:

> "The resource script FILE_PATH.rc was not created using Microsoft
>   Visual Studio.
>  Comments, macros, preprocessor directives, and
>   conditionally included information may be modified and/or removed from
>   this file during the build process. Replace existing file?"

Even if I click "yes" (in order to just test things) then I get all kind of error messages at compile time:

> ResourceCompile:
>   
>   gen\firebreathWin.rc(8): error RC2144: PRIMARY
>   LANGUAGE ID not a number
>
> gen\firebreathWin.rc(16): error RC2135: file not found VS_VERSION_INFO
>
> etc...

I have two questions:

1. What is the correct way to add an image resource which will be added to the compiled plugin using CMake? I searched about it and couldn't find any helping information.
2. What can be the cause for this change in behavior? since I was able to use the same exact steps before and it worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wouldn't do this; instead, I'd just put the file in the same directory as your DLL and use the path of DLL to find it.

That said, the "correct" way to do this would be to see what changes are made to the .rc file when you add it in the IDE, copy the .rc file from gen_templates/ in the root of the firebreath directory into your project, and then make those changes to your copy of the file.  Any changes you make to the generated file will be overridden any time cmake is run again, which can happen any time your cmake files (CMakeLists.txt, *.cmake) change.

Comment: But I want to pack my plugin and have people download it. I have a few images I want to use in the plugin, it will make things more complicated to pack it all up and get the user to download it. Unless I'm missing something.  As for the "correct" way, that's exactly what I did, I changed `firebreathWin.rc` and `resource.h` in  the `FireBreath/gen_templates` directory, but that will affect all of my FB projects... Can't I do this locally in the project?